# MySQL query for renaming part of the URL in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have just imported a database table from a previous site, and one of the table headers has a title of 'enclosure' and in this, there is a big list of URLs, all starting http://richardgordoncook.com/dl/audio/filename.mp3 etc.

I need to change the start of this URL from richardgordoncook.com to richgc.com but I don't know how to be that specific with a query.

I can easily change one:

```
UPDATE `db141188_cnc`.`wp_StreamPad_Tracks` SET `enclosure` = 'http://richgc.com/dl/audio/andy_summers.mp3',
`sourceUrl` = 'http://www.curatorialnoiseclub.com' WHERE `wp_StreamPad_Tracks`.`id` =5 LIMIT 1 ;
```

But I don't want to write each one out.

So, I need to change richardgordoncook.com to richgc.com.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
update <table> 
SET enclosure = replace(enclosure, 'richardgordoncook.com', 'richgc.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableX   
  CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT 'http://richardgordoncook.com'  AS original
           , 'http://richgc.com'             AS replacement
    ) AS c
SET enclosure 
    = CONCAT( replacement
            , RIGHT(enclosure, LEN(enclosure) - LEN(original))
            )
WHERE enclosure LIKE CONCAT(original, '%')
```